# How can I improve my regex string and replacement string to get what I need as output?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want using regex to detect all the new line character (\n) that are put by users by mistake. For example

```
# abcd abcd abcd abcd 
efgh efgh efgh efgh       

   ## ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk 
lmn lmn lmn    

 # opq opq opq opq       
rst rst rest  rst
```

To be corrected to following

```
# abcd abcd abcd abcd efgh efgh efgh efgh 
## ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk lmn lmn lmn 
#opq opq opq opq rst rst rest  rst
```

I am trying to use this regex string :

```
\s*\n+[\s]*[^#]+
```

to be **replaced** by `""` (blank string)

ie. Find a `\n` character that

1. May or may not have multiple spaces before it.
2. Can be followed by multiple spaces
3. But the space following `\n` should not have a `#` after it. Eg. `\n  #` . Because `#` should always start a new line, and if `#` too is included and replaced by `""` it will start appearing on the same line as previous one.

The answer after replacement with \n is this, which is not desired:

```
 # abcd abcd abcd abcdfgh efgh efgh efgh## ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk ijkmn lmn lmn# opq opq opq opqst rst rest  rst
```

How can I improve my regex string and replacement string to get what I need as output?

Comment: Please clarify "But the following space should not have a # after it"

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman I have added more explanation there. I am just trying to explain why I chose the regex string: \s*\n+[\s]*[^#]+   . I am not expert with regex so may be I am wrong in my explanation.

Comment: So you basically trying to append multiple lines where the next line does not start with # ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?:\s*\n)+\s*(?!\s*#)|^\s+|[ \t]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tm52Vt/1)

**Code:**

```js
const s = `# abcd abcd abcd abcd 
efgh efgh efgh efgh       

   ## ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk 
lmn lmn lmn    

 # opq opq opq opq       
rst rst rest  rst
`;

var r = s.replace(/(?:\s*\n)+\s*(?!\s*#)|^\s+|[ \t]*$/mg, '');

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try with that:

```
^[ \t]*([#]+[^\n]+)\n[ \t]*([^#\n]+.*?)\n
```

and replace by this:

```
$1$2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qt3Qu0/1/)

```js
const regex = /^[ \t]*([#]+[^\n]*?)[ \t]*\n[ \t]*([^#\n]+.*?)\n/gm;
const str = `# abcd abcd abcd abcd 
efgh efgh efgh efgh       

   ## ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk ijk 
lmn lmn lmn    

 # opq opq opq opq       
rst rst #rest  rst 
`;
const subst = `$1$2`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There is a small issue I noticed. If you add a new line just before #rest , the new line becomes a part of previous line after substitution.